# Finding Voltage and Current across a capacitor. Will you check my work?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, math

**Question:**
[image: Question]

**Work:** [image: Work]

I have decided to approach this question using a differential equation for practice, but I keep getting an equation that doesn’t seem right. The reason I think this is because for part b, I keep getting -inf or inf for my current or voltage. That obviously can be right. Would you mind checking my work and seeing where I went wrong? I am using KCL with the linear ode method.

Comment: There are five parts to the question. I see one long answer with no parts. I don't know where to stop.

Comment: I will post cleaner work within an hour

Comment: You know steady state is 2/3 * 12V from the equivalent circuit of R3/(R3+R1)V1 steady state and R1//R3 =Req in series with 8V / Req= the initial cap current. The rest can be done in your head in a few seconds after to learn how to do it the hard way.

Comment: I can easily figure it out using capacitive circuit logic and memorized equations. I think I need to do some editing to the post but I am trying to use a linear ODE to challenge myself for the coming midterm. I know it’s not the typical method. That said, I will comment again when I have made my post more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from \$t=0\$, you know that \$V_{C(t=0)}=0\:\textrm{V}\$ and:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_C}{R_1}+\frac{V_C}{R_3}+\frac{\textrm{d}V_C}{\textrm{d}t}C&=\frac{V_0}{R_1}+\frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{R_3}\\\\
\frac{\textrm{d}V_C}{\textrm{d}t}+V_C\left(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_3}\right)\frac{1}{C}&=\frac{V_0}{R_1 \:C}\\\\
\hline\\
V_C^{'} + P_t\: V_C &= Q_t,\\\\& & P_t&=\frac{1}{C\left(R_1\:\mid\mid\: R_3\right)}\\\\
& & Q_t &=\frac{V_0}{R_1 \:C}
\end{align*}$$

Which is in standard form for the obvious solution method used for 1st order linear differential equations.

---

The final solution (now that you've posted your own writing on this) is:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{C}&=V_0\frac{R_3}{R_1+R_3}\left(1- e^{-\frac{-t}{C\cdot\left(R_1\:\mid\mid\:R_3\right)}}\right)\\\\
&=8\left(1-e^{\frac{-t}{2}}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Just as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting every one’s time but I found my mistake. I don’t know how I made the same mistake twice, but no one’s perfect :P

It all came down to my first equation where Ic = something. All of the signs were wrong and that screwed me up from there. Here is my detailed solution for people that end up having the same question as me.

**Solution:**

[image: Solution Page 1]
[image: Solution Page 2]
[image: Solution Page 3]

Comment: Always be suspicious when exponentials go to infinity in a passive circuit.